# TCPDF PDF forms, signing certificates and how to enable user's rights

Tags: php, pdf, certificate, pdf-generation, tcpdf

This is driving me completely and utterly nuts... Basically I have a PDF form generated by TCPDF and want to set the user rights (using setUserRights) for that PDF so that users can save the form with the data they inputted. The TCPDF manual isn't really helpful at this particular point and states that you need a "signing certificate" to enable saving and other extended features.

So I generated an SSL certificate and private using OpenSSL and "imported" them using the  setSignature method. Without using that method Adobe Reader moans:

> This document enabled extended
>   features in Adobe Reader. The document
>   has been changed since it was created
>   and use of extended features is no
>   longer available. Please contact the
>   author for the original version of
>   this document.

When the required setSignature method is set that message doesn't appear, but Reader still can't save the PDF.

```
$this->Pdf->setSignature("file:///certificates/forms.crt", "file:///certificates/forms.key", "somepassword", "", 3);
```

And then I set full user rights:

```
$this->Pdf->setUserRights(true, '/FullSave', '/Create/Delete/Modify/Copy/Import/Export', '/Add/Delete/FillIn/Import/Export/SubmitStandalone/SpawnTemplate', '/Modify');
```

Has anybody worked with this particular feature and is able to point out what I'm doing wrong here?

**Update**

TCPDF includes [an example](http://www.tecnick.com/pagefiles/tcpdf/example_052.phps) using a demo certificate. But it's unclear to me how to obtain such a certificate. Using the demo version still doesn't allow me to set the user's rights properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's appropriate to answer my own question. I've asked this question on the TCPDF forums and got an answer of one of the maintainers of TCPDF.

Basically the answer is that it can't be done. Although the documentation states that:

> Names specifying additional
>   document-wide usage rights for the
>   document. The only defined value is
>   "/FullSave", which permits a user to
>   save the document along with modified
>   form and/or annotation data.

But this is apparently outdated information. It worked in Acrobat Reader 8 using a workaround, but now not anymore. So the only solution is generating your PDF with TCPDF and passing it through Adobe Acrobat and set the user rights there. As my application is a server-side PDF form generator I don't have that option... Or does anybody have a brilliant solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The setUserRights() was working in the past with old Acrobat Reader versions because a bug on these versions.
AFAIK, only official Acrobat products can release user rights using the Adobe Private key.
This means that the setUserRights() doesn't work anymore unless you are Adobe!

Comment: Thanks! I asked the question on the TCPDF forums a while ago as well and got the above answer. A shame though, reading and writing to forms is quite a common feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the setUserRights call? According to the docs that last parameter sets the rights. Perhaps the second call modifies the pdf and thus the signature no longer matches the PDF because it's changed?

Comment: Only setting the signature doesn't affect the document. Acrobat Reader only displays the message when setUserRights is enabled. I'm not allowed to save the form data in either case - with setUserRights set or not.